# Document stamping

Tags: visa-refusals, h1b-visas

I would never asked this question had it not been for this forum that I discovered just by chance although I have been on SO and SE for years! It is a kind of a dated question - back to the 9/11 days. (Please do create a tag for this question if it is missing)

I had been sponsored a work permit and when I went for the visa interview, they informed me that they couldn't issue the visa right away because of some unfilled column in Sales Tax (not the exact terminology) of the company and within a month or so, the 9/11 happened and all immigration got stopped.

Question is, would it be considered as a visa denial if, in future, I fill any column related to the past visa applications to the US, what do I mention as reason - the immigration freeze part, the sales tax column part?

More importantly, does the outcome of the past incident affect the future visa applications and how much? Would it be ok to ask the US embassy of the application status (without projecting myself as being 'aggressive' about it) as due to the subsequent terrorism mess or whatever, the US embassy never updated me on the status as they said they would (Not the "We would get back to you" kind of snub but....) and would, if the status were favorable, the circumstances be considered for a visa waiver ?

Comment: Nitpick: If you're a national of India (and not a dual citizen of anywhere), then you won't qualify for the Visa Waiver Program under any circumstances, so I think the [tag:us-visa-waiver-program] tag is misplaced.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.  I suppose few countries would be likely to hold this against you, but do you have any specific prospective visa application in mind?

In general, if you're in doubt as to whether the incident constitutes a refusal, you should disclose it.  You can explain what happened in a brief statement.

It's also unlikely that you'd bring much trouble on yourself by asking the embassy.  You can explain that you would like to know whether you need to report that application when applying for a new visa.

Comment: Incidentally, I also had a F1 getting processed in parallel, as I had obtained a 100% scholarship from a university in Iowa but the subsequent visa counseling telephonic call with the Dean made me opt for the H1B as the Dean advised that I could always study while working.

Being in the software industry, I guess the opportunities are always there but no, I don't think I believe in applying for a visa unless I have a sponsor. First experience matters, I guess.